# VueJS Element Classes Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am having a problem that may be a bug with vuejs.

This is my navbar. Upon rendering, the classes `ml-0 ml-md-auto` do not show in the browser inspector and their styles are not applied.

This is the source:

```html
<ul v-if="authd" v-bind:class="{nav: true, toggled : bshow_nav }">          
    <li class="nav-item d-block d-md-none"><div class='nav-toggle' @click="bshow_nav = !bshow_nav"><img src="~/assets/images/icons/hamburger_white.svg" alt="Menu" width="24" height="24" /></div></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class='nav-link' href="/profile" >Profile</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/order">Order</a></li>

    <!-- this line -->
    <li class="nav-item ml-0 ml-md-auto"><a href="#" @click.prevent="logout" class='nav-link'>Logout</a></li>

    <li class='nav-item nav-footer'><img src="~/assets/images/voxicard_roundel.svg" alt="Voxicard" width="56" height="56" /></li>
</ul>
```

this is what gets rendered:

```html
<ul class='nav'>
    <li class="nav-item d-block d-md-none"><div class='nav-toggle'><img src="~/assets/images/icons/hamburger_white.svg" alt="Menu" width="24" height="24" /></div></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class='nav-link' href="/profile" >Profile</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/order">Order</a></li>

    <!-- this line; see, there classes are not shown. -->
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class='nav-link'>Logout</a></li>

    <li class='nav-item nav-footer'><img src="~/assets/images/voxicard_roundel.svg" alt="Voxicard" width="56" height="56" /></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried restarting the server, refreshing the page, clearing cache, different browsers, different pages, tried different classes and it still persists and I have absolutely no idea why - its just html!

If i edit anything else, it will update and render in the browser, just not whatever is in the `class` attribute and it stays as just `nav-item`

**HOWEVER**

It begins to work and show when I shrink the screen to a mobile view.
Anyhow, why don't the classes appear on the first render? there's no conditions or functionality that make them appear and disappear on the element, its hard coded into the element.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by removing the `v-else` condition on the sibling element and just having an opposite `v-if` statement like so:

changed this:

```html
<ul v-if="authd" v-bind:class="{nav: true, toggled : bshow_nav }">          
    <li class="nav-item d-block d-md-none"><div class='nav-toggle' @click="bshow_nav = !bshow_nav"><img src="~/assets/images/icons/hamburger_white.svg" alt="Menu" width="24" height="24" /></div></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class='nav-link' href="/profile" >Profile</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/order">Order</a></li>

    <!-- this line -->
    <li class="nav-item ml-0 ml-md-auto"><a href="#" @click.prevent="logout" class='nav-link'>Logout</a></li>

    <li class='nav-item nav-footer'><img src="~/assets/images/voxicard_roundel.svg" alt="Voxicard" width="56" height="56" /></li>
</ul>
<ul v-else>  <!-- FROM THIS HERE -->
...
</ul>
```

to this:

```html
<ul v-if="authd" v-bind:class="{nav: true, toggled : bshow_nav }">          
    <li class="nav-item d-block d-md-none"><div class='nav-toggle' @click="bshow_nav = !bshow_nav"><img src="~/assets/images/icons/hamburger_white.svg" alt="Menu" width="24" height="24" /></div></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class='nav-link' href="/profile" >Profile</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/order">Order</a></li>

    <!-- this line -->
    <li class="nav-item ml-0 ml-md-auto"><a href="#" @click.prevent="logout" class='nav-link'>Logout</a></li>

    <li class='nav-item nav-footer'><img src="~/assets/images/voxicard_roundel.svg" alt="Voxicard" width="56" height="56" /></li>
</ul>
<ul v-if="!authd"> <!-- <<<<< HERE -->
...
</ul>
```

Why did this work? I don't know.

Comment: `authd` is boolean value?, i think that not... then your v-if should be: `v-if="!!authd"` to work with `v-else`

Comment: yes, it is and continues to be a Boolean value. It's weird isn't it? I would never think that this condition statement would be cause of this. I'm thinking of posting as an issue on the github, there' s really some witchcraft going on.